# Abstract Algebra: Index of Subgroups

Tags: group-theory, finite-groups

Here's the problem I'm working on:

Prove: Suppose $H$ has index $p$ and $K$ has index $q$, where $p$ and $q$ are distinct primes. Then the index of $H \cap K$ is a multiple of $pq$. (Plus: do you think this is still true when $G$ is not finite? Explain.)

We have been talking about the index of a subgroup and Lagrange's Theorem, but I am not quite getting it. Here's what I am thinking is the direction to go:

Using Lagrange's Theorem, we know that $|H \cap K| * [G:H \cap K] = |G|$. We also know this applies to both of the subgroups $H$ and $K$ such that $|H| * p = |G|$ and $|K| * q = |G|$. I need to find some way to prove that $[G:H \cap K]$ is equal to $p * q * x$ where $x$ is some integer such that $p * q * x = |G| / |H \cap K|$.

And that is where I am at a loss.

Thanks.

Comment: When you consider the possibility that $G$ is infinite, the equations $|G|=p|H|$ and $|G|=q|K|$ are *strictly weaker* than the original hypotheses $[G:H]=p$ and $[G:K]=q$. Additionally the ratio you have written $|G|/|H\cap K|$ will not make sense, even though the index does. Note my answer does not make reference to nor use of $G$'s cardinality.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Suppose $A\le B\le C$. $\,$ Can you say anything about the indices $[C:A]$, $[C:B]$, $[B:A]$?

Hint: think of them as ratios of numbers, not groups, and make a claim about divisibility.

Now apply to your problem. Can you identify where two cases of $A\le B\le C$ occur implicitly in the problem setup? What can you conclude? Think arithmetic / elementary number theory.

Comment: Okay so here's what I'm thinking you're going for:
We know |H\cap K| <= |H| <= |G| and |H\cap K| <= |K| <= |G|. Now we know that |K| and |H| divides |G|, but what do we do with that? I seem to be missing what you're pointing to. I don't understand what we can claim about divisibility. Can we say that A divides C, B divides C, and A divides B because of those ratios?

Comment: @ThomasL I am emphatically *not* talking about the sizes of the groups! I am talking about the indices! If $A\le B\le C$ then what can you say about $[C:A]$ and $[C:B]$ in relation to each other?

Comment: [C:A] would be greater than or equal to [C:B].

Comment: True, but you can say something stronger than that.

Comment: Would [C:B] divide [C:A]? But if so, why?

Comment: Yes. Are you aware $C\ge B\ge A\,\Rightarrow\,[C:A]=[C:B][B:A]$?

Comment: No, I wasn't actually, but that helps quite a bit. So I would say because |G| ≥ |H| ≥ |H∩ K|, then [G:H∩ K]= [G:H]*[H:H∩ K]. And therefore the index of H∩K would be divisible by p and similarly for q. Correct?

Comment: That's correct. If it's divisible by $p$ and $q$, it's divisible by $pq$, since they are distinct primes. As for why the index is multiplicative: if $X$ is a left transversal for $C/B$ and $Y$ a left transversal for $B/A$, then $$C=\bigsqcup_{x\in X} xB=\bigsqcup_{x\in X}x\bigsqcup_{y\in Y}yA=\bigsqcup_{xy\in XY}xyA$$ hence $XY=\{xy:x\in X,y\in Y\}$ is a left-transversal for $C/A$, where $\bigsqcup$ means "disjoint union." For more information see e.g. http://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Index_is_multiplicative